# Firebase : I can retrieve the key but not the value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve the value of the snapshot using this code :

```
mDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Salarie");
mDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override

    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),snapshot.getKey(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Salarié salarié = snapshot.getValue(Salarié.class);
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),salarié.getDepartement(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

My javaBean looks like this :

```
public class Salarié {
    private String departement;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }
    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setDepartement(String département) {
        this.departement = département;
    }
    public String getDepartement() {
        return departement;
    }
}
```

My database looks like this :

```
"40" : {
    "Departement" : "EXEMPLE",
    "Nom" : "EX1",
    "Prenom" : "EX2"
},
```

The problem is during debugging I can see that snapshot has the value, but when I try to show it through the variable salarié I get nothing.

Comment: getting any error?

Comment: try changing your Salarie class variables first alphabet to capital. i.e "department" to "Department"

Comment: Or try using the PropertyName annotation, like this
`@PropertyName(PROP_NAME)
private String mName;`

Comment: @MohammedJunaid When i tried your solution the app crashed.

Comment: @NabilaK what was the crash log?

Comment: Please specify the exception

Comment: 07-24 10:18:58.337: E/AndroidRuntime(15052): com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: departement

Comment: after renaming your variables did you renamed the Getter methods Parameters too? if not then do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),snapshot.getKey(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String department = (String)snapshot.child("Departement").getValue();


    }
}
```

I have shown you fetching the department name,like that you can try to get all values.

Comment: This worked but i'm not just trying to get the value of the departement i need the value of the entire salarié

Comment: You can create an List of Model type and add value to that model.

Comment: Or have it instantiated create an Instance Class so that you can have all your data so that you can access your data

Comment: That's what i ended up doing. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Problem is naming of variables in model class.
You need to change the name of variables as below :-

```
public class Salarié {

    private String Departement; //must be same as firebase response
    private String Nom;
    private String Prenom;

    public String getDepartement() {
        return Departement;
    }

    public void setDepartement(String departement) {
        Departement = departement;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return Nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        Nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return Prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        Prenom = prenom;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have your setters/getters into Serialized Class because your Firebase is in JSON format

For your `Salarie class` changed it to this make sure you have `GSON library` is enabled in your Application mine is:

```
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

**Salarie Class:**

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties    
public class Salarie {

       @SerializedName("Departement")
       public String Departement;

       @SerializedName("Nom")
       public String Nom;

       @SerializedName("PreNom")
       public String PreNom;
}
```

**Code:**

```
mDB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Salarie");
mDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

           for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),snapshot.getKey(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Salarie salarie = snapshot.getValue(Salarie.class);
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(),salarie.Departement,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Make Sure that when you query use the `Query` function on Firebase when you wanted to find the data.